# how perform .add( .shift() ) on a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to manipulate a jQuery object to make the first item the last, second the first, third the second, and so on.

With an Array this would be simple:

```
myArray = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ];
myArray.add( myArray.shift() );
// done.
```

How can I do this with a jQuery object?

```
myObject = $('.myDiv').children();
myObject.nowWhat(?)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do it:
**UPDATES:**

```
arr = $('.myDiv').children().get();
myObject = $(arr);  //wrapped it again to a jquery object
myObject.add( arr.shift() );
myObject.someJQueryEventFunc();
```

get() returns an array of all the matched elements.

get(index) returns a single element of the matched elements

Comment: doesn't work. slide
            TypeError: Result of expression 'slidePointers.shift' [undefined] is not a function.

Comment: Ok, i got it to work with the .get()
But you can't .add() to an array. If I change it to push, everything works.

Comment: this should do it:

arr= $('.myDiv').children().get();
myObject = $(arr);
myObject.add( arr.shift() );
myObject.someJqueryFuncHere();

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.myDiv').find(':first').remove().appendTo('.myDiv');
```

However, it would be better to identify the div with an ID and not a class as this won't do quite what you expect if you have more than one element with class myDiv. In that case you'll have to do this:

```
$('.myDiv').each(function (index, div) {
    $(div).find(':first').remove().appendTo(div);
});
```

You can wrap this in a function to perform the functionality described in your comment:

```
transformFirstThree('.myDiv');
rotate('.myDiv');
transformFirstThree('.myDiv')


function transformFirstThree (selector) {
    $(selector).find(':lt(3)').each(function (index, item) {
        // do whatever
    });
}

function rotate (selector) {
    $(selector).each(function (index, div) {
        $(div).find(':first').remove().appendTo(div);
    });
}
```

Comment: Not completely what I need. I use the myObject to apply 3 different functions on the first 3 items. After that, the object items need to shift one place up so I can perform the functions again.

I'm trying to make a carousel.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $('.mydiv').children();
console.log (x[0]);
console.log (x[1]);
var arr= x.slice (1);
arr.push(x[0]);
console.log (arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/ -- it converts array-like structures to true JS arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had to implement something like this. Basically what I've done is:

```
$parent
    .find(elementSelector + ':lt(' + numberOfElementsToShift + ')')
    .insertAfter($parent.find(elementSelector + ':last'));
```

In your case, `numberOfElementsToShift` would be `1`. `$parent` could be an unordered list, `elementSelector` could be the string `li`, for example.

What it does is select the first `numberOfElementsToShift` of elements and move them to the end of all the elements.

Seems more efficient to move the element(s) straight to the end once than to shift them `n - numberOfElementsToShift` times.